# java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry

Tags: java

I am trying to create a csv file and zip it. The problem i am seeing is its not having columns which i am trying to have, i see only 164 columns with the below strings (present in string array).
It looks like the reason for this exception is the size (i.e. byte size count of column names in csv) is exceeding 8192 bytes. How to increase this limit, or any other solution?

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.write(ZipOutputStream.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:269)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:50)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.printWithQuotes(CSVFormat.java:1475)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.print(CSVFormat.java:1224)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.print(CSVFormat.java:1210)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat.printRecord(CSVFormat.java:1322)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter.printRecord(CSVPrinter.java:271)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter.<init>(CSVPrinter.java:110)
    at Test.main(Test.java:216)
```

sample test.java file

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            String [] csvHeaderElements = {

                   
                    "onethree_onethreeFour0",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour1",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour2",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour3",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour4",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour5",


                    "onethree_onethreeFour6",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour7",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour8",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour9",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour10",


                    "onethree_onethreeFour11",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour12",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour13",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour14",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour15",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour16",
                    "onethree_onethreeFour17",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_dtx",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_ack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_nack",
                    "onetwothree_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_dtx",

                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_nack",

                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec0_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec1_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec2_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec3_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec4_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec5_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec6_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_nack",

                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec7_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec8_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec9_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec10_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec11_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec12_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_nack",

                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec13_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec14_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_nack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec1_onetwo0_onetwo_rec15_dtx",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec2_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_ack",
                    "onetwothreefour_onetwothreefour_rec2_onetwo0_onetwo_rec0_nack"

                    
            };
            ServletOutputStream out = new ServletOutputStream() {
                @Override
                public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println(b);
                }
            };

            int count = 0;
            for(String str : csvHeaderElements) {
                count += str.length();

            }
            System.out.println("size " + count);

            System.out.println("size of array is " + csvHeaderElements.length);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(out);

            CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(zos),
                    CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader(csvHeaderElements)
                    //CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(csvHeaderElements)
            );
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do there. Why the override?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a zip by just copying the contents of a CSV file to it, you need to create a zip entry first. So the code should look like this:

```
String[] csvHeaderElements = { // some headers separated with semicolon
        };
try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/TestUser/Downloads/test.zip"))) {
    // create zip entry
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("test.csv");
    zos.putNextEntry(entry);

    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(new OutputStreamWriter(zos), CSVFormat.EXCEL.builder().setHeader(csvHeaderElements).build());
    // some action with csvPrinter
    // ...

    // close entry
    zos.closeEntry();
}
```

Comment: This code unnecessarily consumes additional memory by using a ByteArrayOutputStream as an intermediary. Creating the entry before the CSVPrinter should work fine (though maybe you need a close guard to prevent the CSVPrinter from closing the entire zip.

Comment: @mark-rotteveel you are perfectly right, answer edited

Comment: Thanks for answers. I added more strings in string array, but i only see 164 columns, it looks like first 8192 bytes column names size are added. Please let me know how to get all columns i.e all the strings in string array.  I used the code snippet presented above, i dont see exception now, but not all columns are seen.

Answer (score 2):

ZIP streams require an entry - which will set up filename within the ZIP content. Use try with resources to ensure that ZIP output stream is closed correctly. This example defines the content within entry called "somename.xyz":

```
try(ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(out)) {
    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("somename.xyz"));

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(zos);
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(wr,
      CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader(csvHeaderElements)
    );
    // ...
    csvPrinter.flush();
}
```

Note that the stream encoder used within OutputStreamWriter has a buffer size of 8192, so your secondary issue with CSV columns clipped at 8192 is likely to be that you are missing `csvPrinter.flush();` after dealing with the CSV printing.

Or perhaps you are confusing with GZIP stream which would be simpler to setup, just change `ZipOutputStream`  to `GZIPOutputStream`:

```
try(GZIPOutputStream zos = new GZIPOutputStream(out)) {
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(zos);
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(wr,
      CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader(csvHeaderElements)
    );
    // ...
    csvPrinter.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working after calling flush() when i run as standalone program. When i run the same piece of code from jsp i.e. when i try to have zip file be downloaded by user (zip file is constructed in memory i.e i mean zip file is not stored on server), i am using zipoutputstream which is constructed with taking argument servletoutpustream, i see the error "java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry" even though csvPrinter.flush() method is called after writing each file i.e after calling zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry); Please suggest anything to do in case of jsp/servlet case.

Comment: Same code or a copy? If your main works, perhaps you should refactor to a method that you then call from main and the jsp - adding unit testcases for the new method.

Comment: I was able to resolve the "java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry" by calling first zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry); and then followed by csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(zos),
                    CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(ARRAY); (Here ARRAY is the array of strings)

Comment: Thanks EveryOne who responded in this thread, your answers gave me direction and also knowledge.